# Cannot find Power Management Tab in XP

Tags: windows-xp, mouse, power-management

I have the problem that when I send my computer to sleep it wakes if you bump the table, floor, burp etc. I have read many threads that say go to Device Manager > Mouse > Properties > Power Management Tab and uncheck the box for wake.

My problem is I do not have a Power Management Tab! Anyone know how to enable the tab or stop the mouse from waking my machine?

And no, turning it upside down doesn't work either!

Comment: do you have a PS/2 mouse with the standard windows driver? Afaik that does not have a power managment tab, only usb mice do

Comment: @stijn - I have a PS2 mouse

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a USB mouse, look at Device Manager > USB Controller > (your Mouse) > Power Management > "allow this device to wake the computer".

There are probably many devices shown if you expand the "USB Controller" tree view (usb hubs etc.), you'll have to find your mouse, it's most likely named like "Human Interface Device (HID)" or something like that.